# App in GKE works with TCP health check but returns 404 with HTTP health check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, istio

I have a GKE cluster with Istio deployed in it. I have added the clusters node-pool instance groups to the backend of a GCP HTTP(S) LB.

To perform health check on the backends I have created the following health-check:

```
name: gke-http-hc    
path: /healthz/ready (istio-ingressgateway readinessProbe path)
port: 30302 (for this the target port is 15021, which is the status port of istio-ingressgateway)
Protocol: HTTP
```

I can see that the health checks are all successful. But, if I try to access my application with my app URL, I get 404 error.

But, if I apply a TCP type health check and access the application with the app URL, I get the desired response 200 OK.

The TCP health check has following config:

```
name: gke-tcp-hc
Protocol: TCP
Port: 31397 (for this the target post is 80)
```

Why does my app behave differently for HTTP and TCP health-checks? Is there any other configuration I need to do to make the HTTP health check (query istio-ingressgateway's status) work?

Following are my k8s manifests for istio-ingressgateway:

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource-namespace: istio-system
    istio: ingressgateway
    istio.io/rev: default
    operator.istio.io/component: IngressGateways
    operator.istio.io/managed: Reconcile
    operator.istio.io/version: 1.9.5
    release: istio 
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
      istio: ingressgateway
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 100%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/path: /stats/prometheus
        prometheus.io/port: "15020"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: istio-ingressgateway
        chart: gateways
        heritage: Tiller
        install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
        istio: ingressgateway
        istio.io/rev: default
        operator.istio.io/component: IngressGateways
        release: istio
        service.istio.io/canonical-name: istio-ingressgateway
        service.istio.io/canonical-revision: latest
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - amd64
            weight: 2
          - preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - ppc64le
            weight: 2
          - preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - s390x
            weight: 2
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - amd64
                - ppc64le
                - s390x
      containers:
      - args:
        - proxy
        - router
        - --domain
        - $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
        - --proxyLogLevel=warning
        - --proxyComponentLogLevel=misc:error
        - --log_output_level=default:info
        - --serviceCluster
        - istio-ingressgateway
        env:
        - name: JWT_POLICY
          value: third-party-jwt
        - name: PILOT_CERT_PROVIDER
          value: istiod
        - name: CA_ADDR
          value: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: INSTANCE_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: HOST_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
        - name: SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
        - name: CANONICAL_SERVICE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.labels['service.istio.io/canonical-name']
        - name: CANONICAL_REVISION
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.labels['service.istio.io/canonical-revision']
        - name: ISTIO_META_WORKLOAD_NAME
          value: istio-ingressgateway
        - name: ISTIO_META_OWNER
          value: kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/istio-ingressgateway
        - name: ISTIO_META_UNPRIVILEGED_POD
          value: "true"
        - name: ISTIO_META_ROUTER_MODE
          value: standard
        - name: ISTIO_META_CLUSTER_ID
          value: Kubernetes
        image: docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.9.5
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: istio-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 15021
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 15012
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 15443
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 15090
          name: http-envoy-prom
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 30
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz/ready
            port: 15021
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 2
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
          privileged: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/proxy
          name: istio-envoy
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/config
          name: config-volume
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/istio
          name: istiod-ca-cert
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/tokens
          name: istio-token
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /var/lib/istio/data
          name: istio-data
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/pod
          name: podinfo
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs
          name: ingressgateway-certs
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs
          name: ingressgateway-ca-certs
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1337
        runAsGroup: 1337
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1337
      serviceAccount: istio-ingressgateway-service-account
      serviceAccountName: istio-ingressgateway-service-account
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: istio-ca-root-cert
        name: istiod-ca-cert
      - downwardAPI:
          defaultMode: 420
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.labels
            path: labels
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.annotations
            path: annotations
          - path: cpu-limit
            resourceFieldRef:
              containerName: istio-proxy
              divisor: 1m
              resource: limits.cpu
          - path: cpu-request
            resourceFieldRef:
              containerName: istio-proxy
              divisor: 1m
              resource: requests.cpu
        name: podinfo
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: istio-envoy
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: istio-data
      - name: istio-token
        projected:
          defaultMode: 420
          sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              audience: istio-ca
              expirationSeconds: 43200
              path: istio-token
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: istio
          optional: true
        name: config-volume
      - name: ingressgateway-certs
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          optional: true
          secretName: istio-ingressgateway-certs
      - name: ingressgateway-ca-certs
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          optional: true
          secretName: istio-ingressgateway-ca-certs
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource-namespace: istio-system
    istio: ingressgateway
    istio.io/rev: default
    operator.istio.io/component: IngressGateways
    operator.istio.io/managed: Reconcile
    operator.istio.io/version: 1.9.5
    release: istio
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.30.192.198
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: status-port
    nodePort: 30302
    port: 15021
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15021
  - name: http2
    nodePort: 31397
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    nodePort: 32343
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  - name: tcp-istiod
    nodePort: 30255
    port: 15012
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15012
  - name: tls
    nodePort: 30490
    port: 15443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15443
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

Here are my app manifests:

Deployment:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-st-sc5ght
    release: app-st-sc5ght
    heritage: Helm
    chart: app-chart
  name: app-st-sc5ght
  namespace: app-st
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-st-sc5ght
      release: app-st-sc5ght
      heritage: Helm
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
        release: app-st-sc5ght
        heritage: Helm
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-key
      volumes:
        - name: app-config
          configMap:
            name: app-st-config
      containers:
        - image: reg.org.jp/app:1.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: app
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu:  0.2
            limits:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: 0.5
          env:
            - name: STDOUT_STACKDRIVER_LOG
              value: '1'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: app-config
              mountPath: /app_config
              readOnly: true
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /status
              port: 9000
            initialDelaySeconds: 11
            periodSeconds: 7
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /status
              port: 9000
            initialDelaySeconds: 3
            periodSeconds: 5
```

Service:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-st-sc5ght
  namespace: app-st
  labels:
    app: app-st-sc5ght
    release: app-st-sc5ght
    heritage: Helm
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    nodePort: 32098
    targetPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    name: app-web
  selector:
    app: app-st-sc5ght
```

DestinationRule:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: app-st-sc5ght
  namespace: app-st
  labels:
    app: app-st-sc5ght
    release: app-st-sc5ght
    heritage: Helm
spec:
  host: app-st-sc5ght.app-st.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: stable
    labels:
      track: stable
      version: stable
  - name: rollout
    labels:
      track: rollout
      version: rollout
```

Gateway:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: app-st-sc5ght
  namespace: app-st
  labels:
    app: app-st-sc5ght
    release: app-st-sc5ght
    heritage: Helm
    track: stable
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: app-st-sc5ght
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
      - st.app.org
```

VirtualService:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: app-st-sc5ght
  namespace: app-st
  labels:
    app: app-st-sc5ght
    release: app-st-sc5ght
    heritage: Helm
    track: stable
spec:
  gateways:
  - app-st-sc5ght
  hosts:
  - st.app.org
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /status
    headers:
      request:
        add:
          endpoint: status
      response:
        add:
          endpoint: status
          version: 1.0.1
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9000
        host: app-st-sc5ght.app-st.svc.cluster.local
        subset: stable
      weight: 100
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9000
        host: app-st-sc5ght.app-st.svc.cluster.local
        subset: rollout
      weight: 0
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /public/list/v4/
    rewrite:
      uri: /list/v4/
    headers:
      request:
        add:
          endpoint: list
      response:
        add:
          endpoint: list
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9000
        host: app-st-sc5ght.app-st.svc.cluster.local
        subset: stable
      weight: 100
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9000
        host: app-st-sc5ght.app-st.svc.cluster.local
        subset: rollout
      weight: 0
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    headers:
      request:
        add:
          endpoint: home
      response:
        add:
          endpoint: home
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9000
        host: app-st-sc5ght.app-st.svc.cluster.local
        subset: stable
      weight: 100
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9000
        host: app-st-sc5ght.app-st.svc.cluster.local
        subset: rollout
      weight: 0
```

Comment: Please add your yaml files to the question and describe what exactly (and how) did you deploy?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak which yaml files specifically?

Comment: Your all yaml files to reproduce your problem. Which version of Istio did you use?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak I have added all the yaml file related to my app and I am using ```v1.9.5``` of istio.

Comment: You are using very old version of Istio. Could you upgrade it to supported one? Look at [this site](https://istio.io/latest/docs/releases/supported-releases/) for more information.